# removing duplicate posts from the list(200M) of already crawled posts

Tags: python, scrapy, duplicates

I have a crawler in python using scrapy crawling posts from a website, there are millions of posts on that site. Each post has a unique post_id, the new requirement from my customer is not to deliver the posts that are already delivered.

From the first look, it looked really simple, have a unique list of post_ids in the set and filtering them. But the issue comes when I've already delivered 200M+ posts, and creating a set of these 200M+ is breaking the process as I've limited RAM and disk space. I've already tried sqldict but it is time-consuming and also breaks the process.

Can you suggest a data structure that has the ability to use less RAM/disk space and is also not time-consuming?

We've to keep in mind that the process does not share any infrastructure, they're independent docker containers, and there are no DB available.

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).